# can't add/include css to my controller using codeigniter template

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

This is weird or stupid question.

I am using codeigniter template library. It works fine but my only problem is that I can't include my css and javascript on the controller. I am including it to the view (html page) and still works fine.

My question is, how can I include the css and javascript on the controller?

I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
$this->template->add_css('resources/css/template/style.css');
```

Currently I am calling it to the view like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= CSSPATH ?>template/style.css">
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `link_tag()`. [https://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use link_tag() and put it on my controller but it gives me an error Call to undefined function link_tag().

Comment: Load the helper `$this->load->helper('html');`

Comment: @SreelalPMohan Just a note it is www.codeigniter.com now, not ellislab.